# List of permissions for a folder and it's subfolder

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, powershell-2.0

I am using PowerShell on Windows 7. I have the following code snippet and wanted to know

Why am I not getting the SID to translate to a friendly username (on the domain)?

```
$OutFile = "I:\Permissions.csv"
$RootPath = "K:\FolderName"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs)
    {

        $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($ACL.IdentityReference.Value) 
        #$objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) 
        $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $objUser.Value


        #Show User
        Write-Host “`r`nThe user mapped to SID $($objSID) is $($objUser.value)`r`n” -f “Red”

        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $objUser.Value  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

Desired Output would be the SAM account name. (not the Display Name)

```
John.Smith1
John.Smith
```

Comment: Please supply a working sample. `$ACL` is never declared.

Comment: here you go. what do you think?

Comment: Better, still missing `$Dname` and `$outfile`, but I created a dummy-object to get past that. see updated answer.

Comment: $DName was something I was trying based on the answers below.

Comment: `.IdentityReference.Value` should already provide a "friendly username". Why are you trying to translate that to an SID and then back to a username? An example of actual and desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`IdentityReference` is a `SecurityIdentifier`-object or `NTAccount`-object, not the SID-value as a string, which is what you would need for the `SecurityIdentifier` constructor. If you need to access the SID as a string, you need to access `$ACL.IdentityReference.Value`.

Try this:

```
$RootPath = "K:\FolderName"
#Define $OutFile
#Define $Dname

$Folders = dir $RootPath | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname

    $ACLs.Access | ForEach-Object { 
        $ACL = $_

        #IdentityReference may already be a SID- or a NTAccount-object. 
        #Get SID-object
        $objSID = $ACL.IdentityReference.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        #Translate to NTAccount-object
        $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]) 

        #Show User
        Write-Host "`r`nThe user mapped to SID $($objSID) is $($objUser.value)`r`n" -f "Red"

        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $DName.Value  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }
}
```

Comment: are you suggesting that I change it to $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($ACL.IdentityReference.Value)

Comment: Yes, if `$ACL` includes that property. You haven't showed us how you got the `$ACL`-object.

Comment: Just tried that and no change. My objUser.Value is not the friendly name in the AD. It's empty in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fairly simple ADSI lookup to pull the user's distinguishedname. Try this out:

```
$DName = ([adsi]"LDAP://<SID=$($ACL.IdentityReference.value)>").distinguishedName
```

$DName should now contain a string with something like 'CN=JSmith,OU=Users,DC=something,DC=com'

To just get the user's name from that you can split the string a couple times since it is `=` and `,` delimited:

```
$strUser = $dname.split("=")[1].split(",")[0]
```

Comment: How do i just get the CN part?

Answer (score -1):

To translate a SID String to an NTAccount:

```
$exampleSidString = 'S-1-5-21-768745588-123456789-987654321-500'
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $exampleSidString
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] )
$objUser.Value
```

However, if you already have an Identity Reference (of which both SecurityIdentifier and NTAccount are subclasses), you can go straight to the transate function:

```
$objUser = $ACL.IdentityReference.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] )
$objUser.Value
```

Check [this link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/ad/archive/2010/10/07/using-powershell-to-resolve-sids-to-friendly-names.aspx) out for more information

Comment: God no. That's just an example SID. He wants to translate the SID in an ACL (`$ACL.IdentityReference`).

Comment: Go to http://blogs.technet.com/ for more information, there is more example from actual Microsoft techs

Comment: I've tried this and I am getting exceptions. Like <<Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s): "The trust relationship bet
ween this workstation and the primary domain failed.>>